# how to sort by value of a tuple in dictionary using lambda?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

how to sort by value of a tuple in a dictionary?

I was using lambda to sort
I tried to sort by name alphabetically and by grade.
so I want to two result separately.

```
scale = {'A+': 4.3, 'A': 4.0, 'A-': 3.7,
   'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7,
   'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0, 'C-': 1.7,
   'D+': 1.3, 'D': 1.0, 'D-': 0.7,
   'F' : 0.0}


subject = {'math':  {('Tom', 'B'), ('Kevin','D')},
   'History':  {('Kate', 'A+'),('Eric','C'),('Hannah','F')}, 
   'English':  {('Eli', 'B-')}}`

from collections import defaultdict
def pass(subject, mingrade):
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for subject_name,subject_grade in subject.items():
        for student,grade in subject_grade:
            if scale[grade]>=mingrade:
                output[subject_name]+=[student]
    return output
```

I have tired like this code to sort by grade but it gets TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
    `for k,v in sorted(db.items(), key =lambda x:x[1][1]):`
however, 
    `for k,v in sorted(db.items(), key =lambda x:x[1])`
does not change anything but does not get error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I left the same comment on another question of yours: why are the values of `subject` sets of tuples instead of being `dict`s in their own right? `subject = {'math': {'Tom': 'B', 'Kevin': 'D'}, ...}`. The conversion is trivial: `subject = {k: dict(v) for k,v in subject.items()}`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you were trying to use (in a way others can run it).

Comment: I have to keep it that way.. and if I put    'subject = {k: dict(v) for k,v in subject.items()}'   before for loop, it gets ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following, if I understand correctly:

```
students, ranking = {}, {}
for s, grades in subject.items():
    ranking[s] = [n for n, g in sorted(grades, key=lambda x: scale[x[1]], reverse=True))]
    students[s] = [n for n, g in sorted(grades, key=lambda x: x[0]))]
```

Comment: could you write it full code? I confused where I should put that code since I want another condition

Comment: That would be difficult as the code in the question doesn't show where the error is coming from. Please update the question.

Comment: can you make dictionary variable instead of print them?
`for s, grades in subject.items():`
   I want like ` subject = (s, sorted(grades, key=lambda x: scale[x[1]], reverse=True))`
so I can use dictionary again

Comment: A dictionary or set is not ordered, do you mean a list?

Comment: yes as long as my output look like {'math': ['Tom','Kevin']}

Comment: That should be what you are looking for now or at least give you something to start with.

Comment: thank you. how would you put that code into my function?